# Is there a list of server models and specifications online? A web service perhaps?

Tags: configuration, hardware

Ideally, I'm looking for an online database that has a REST API that I can query with device make and models and get back some standard configuration data on on that model.

For example, given an IBM x3850, I would want to know:

- Height in RU
- Width
- Weight
- Number of NICs
- NUmber of HDDs
- etc.

Does anyone know a good website with this?  Maybe a webservice that wraps all those entries on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dell_PowerEdge_Servers)?

Answer (score 2):

No, at least I never heard of something like that.

First, why would anyone be interested to do the considerable work necessary and what would he gain from it?

Second, I don't think it's even possible given the fact that sometimes the same model number can describe quite different systems, not to mention the various BTO options you usually have with servers.

Answer (score 0):

Given the dynamics of server specs I really doubt a "universal" type of site would remain current long enough to be of any real value. Better stick to the manufacturers' sites.